# Wordpress Plugin - T_FUNCTION Error - Why?

Tags: php, wordpress

i created a wordpress plugin and a friend of mine tried to activate it. It's weird because I don't get this error but my friend does. After pressing the button he gets the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in
>   /home2/tomlibra/public_html/test/wp-content/plugins/ohhh_voting/inc/class-voting.php
>   on line 49

This is line 46-52 of that file and I can't find the error:

```
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'register_admin_menu') );
        //CSS
        add_action('admin_print_styles', function() {
            $myStyleFile =  plugins_url( 'css/voting_admin.css', dirname(__FILE__) ) ;
            wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet_voting',$myStyleFile,false,'1.0');
        });//add_action
```

This code is within a class, that's why i use (array($this, 'register_admin_menu). Line 49 is exactly this one:

```
        add_action('admin_print_styles', function() {
```

Would be glad if somebody can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Anonymous functions are only supported on 5.3+. Upgrade to a version that supports anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Anonymous` are supported after on PHP 5.3 + consider updating your PHP installation or avoid using it.

Comment: It's an anonymous function, not a closure.

Comment: What do you mean with anonymous function? Do i have to make:
 add_action('admin_print_styles', array($this, 'myfunc'));
function myfunc() { ...

to ensure that it is working < php 5.3